# jquery post add wrong charset to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, character-encoding

I have a problem with the charset config somewhere - and need some help.

I am using a jQuery jeditable to update values to a database through php. When I post `øæå` through this script, the database is populated with `Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥` instead. I've tried to utf8_encode aswell, but with no luck. A regular post with `øæå` works fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.update_pipu_comment').editable('http://lin01.test.no/save.php?update=pipu_comment',   {
        event : 'dblclick',
        submit : 'ok',
        indicator : '<img src="image/indicator.gif">',
        tooltip : 'doubleclick to edit'
    });
});
```

```php
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php 
//save.php
require('config.php');
$postvalue = $_POST[value];
$id = $_POST[id];
$update = $_GET[update];

if($update == 'pipu_comment')   {
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE pinpuk SET comment = '$postvalue' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
echo $postvalue;
```

Comment: Was your DB set with charset UTF8?

Comment: This was just asked like 5 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737875/mysql-outputs-western-encoding-in-utf-8-php-file/

Comment: for a trained eye, like yours - might be, but I read the answer on the question you posted the link to Mamsaac and wouldn't have found the solution based on the answer to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set charset first to UTF-8:

```
$query = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'";
mysql_query($query); // this before any insert
```

Also your code is not SQL safe:

```
$postvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

As a side note, you should try to move to MySQLi or PDO. [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial to get you started in using PDO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll sure read the tutorial you suggested. The code you suggested worked perfectly.